# Is date2num still in the updated Mplfinance interpreter?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, mplfinance

I have been converting JSON data into a pandas table, but I still need to convert datetime string to a float so that the mplfinance interpreter is able to read and plot the data. But there is an issue with one of the packages in the interpreter when trying to execute the code.

Does anyone know why the updated version of mpl_finance doesn't have this date2num package (as far as I know)? This code used to work on the previous version of mpl_finance, but for some reason I'm not able to use the 'date2num' package.

What can be an alternative way to make this work?

```
import mplfinance as mpf

import datetime

from mplfinance import date2num

#Convert date string to date float

float_date = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(df['date'], '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f'))

print(aapl_df)

mpf.plot(aapl_df)
```

---

Here is what I have so far:

```py
import requests #for http request to Marketstack.com
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'access_key': '*********************'
}

#Sorts the data into a table
api_result = requests.get('HTTP API LINK/REQUEST', params)
api_response = api_result.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(api_response['data'])
print(df)

aapl_df = df[['date', 'high', 'open', 'low', 'close', 'adj_close']]
print(aapl_df)

import mplfinance as mpf
import datetime
#Convert date string to date float
float_date = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(df['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f'))

print(aapl_df)
mpf.plot(aapl_df)
```

So I'm able to print the data, but the wrong date format is what creates the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `date2num()` is not and never was part of mplfinance (nor mpl_finance).
- `date2num` is part of matplotlib.
- the *old* mpl_finance required you to convert dates to matplotlib number representation of dates.  Thus, in the old days, you needed to call date2num on your dates.
- **the *new* mplfinance does not require this conversion**.  Rather it expects the data in the form of a **Pandas DataFrame with a Pandas DatetimeIndex**.
- if your data is JSON, i suggest you call **`pandas.read_json()`** to create the dataframe.

I strongly recommmend you take the 10 or 15 minutes necessary to carefully read the new mplfinance basic-usage documentation:

- https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#usage

The first part of the documenation there calls `pandas.read_csv()` which you could replace with **`pandas.read_json()`** and most likely everything else will work the same.

If you post your data here, along with all your code (at least from the point of reading in the data, to the point of calling `mpf.plot()`) then possibly I could help you make it work.

---

- Try the following changes, beginning on the line where you assign `aapl_df`:

```py
###aapl_df = df[['date', 'high', 'open', 'low', 'close', 'adj_close']]

aapl_df = df[['high', 'open', 'low', 'close']]

#Convert date string to datetime index:
aapl_df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])

print(aapl_df)

import mplfinance as mpf

###import datetime
####Convert date string to date float
###float_date = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(df['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f'))

print(aapl_df)
mpf.plot(aapl_df)
```

I am partly taking a guess that this will work;  It would be better if I could see the output from `api_response = api_result.json()`.  Nonetheless, give this a try and let me know how it works.

If `aapl_df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])` raises an exception, then try:

```
aapl_df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'].values)
```

Comment: Ah I see, no wonder I'm confused. Ok here is what I have so far, do you know what I could add?edit to make it work?

Comment: Thanks.  That definitely helps me see what you are doing.  I've moved your response from an answer up into your question (where it belongs).  It would be helpful if I could see the output from `api_response = api_result.json()`; nonetheless I've take a shot at correcting your code by using `pd.DatetimeIndex()` to convert the date strings.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Yes, both methods worked perfectly :) Appreciate the help Mr. Goldfarb!!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  Please up-vote, and click the check-mark, next to the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I clicked the check mark :) The up-vote I also did, but it is under review since I have under 15 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks!   I'm glad my adivce was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests #for http request to Marketstack.com
import pandas as pd

params = {
'access_key': '*********************'
}

#Sorts the data into a table
api_result = requests.get('HTTP API LINK/REQUEST', params)
api_response = api_result.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(api_response['data'])
print(df)

aapl_df = df[['date', 'high', 'open', 'low', 'close', 'adj_close']]
print(aapl_df)

import mplfinance as mpf
import datetime
#Convert date string to date float
float_date = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(df['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%f'))

print(aapl_df)
mpf.plot(aapl_df)
```

So I'm able to print the data, but the wrong date format is what creates the error.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  You may want to delete this answer (since it belongs as part of the question, and has already been added there).  All the best.